# DB2 - Error accessing a table space SQL 57048

Tags: restore, db2

Please can you assist me,I am mighty new at DB2, I done a backup on the prod server in order to mirror the prod server on another server. Backups ran fine. I did the restore on my test server. but trying to connect to the database brings back an roll forward pending error . I then did the 'db2 rollforward db database to end of backup and complete' command.
This command than brought back an error of SQL0293N error accessing a table space container.

Please can you ad advise me.

Thanks

Comment: Please post the exact `restore` command that you ran and the complete error message. It might be useful to look what error appears in `db2diag.log` at the time of rolling forward. Are container paths the same on both servers?